# How are EBP, ESP, and the region between the previous ESP and current EBP aligned on the call stack by gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, callstack, abi

My understanding is that, to accomodate the x86 extension Streaming SIM Extensions (SSE) gcc aligns the stack on 16 byte boundaries. Consider ubuntu 16.04 (32-bit x86) with gcc version 4.8.4. What sections of the stack get aligned to a 16-byte boundary?

My question as a whole is about data-alignment on the stack and how the stack is aligned by gcc. There are 3 positions I am curious about, EBP, ESP, and the region between the previous ESP and new EBP.

From textbooks I know that EBP points to an address where the previous frame pointer is stored. Is EBP considered the bottom of the stack? Is there padding inserted before or after pushing the previous frame pointer to the stack?

I also know that ESP points to the top of the stack. Must ESP also be 16 byte aligned? Is there padding placed at the top of the stack to align ESP to a 16 byte boundary?

With most confusion, what about the regions of data between the new EBP and previous ESP. This is the place where function arguments and the return address in the caller are pushed. Are these considered to be part of the previous stack frame or current stack frame? How must this section of data be aligned?

This is a grey area for me. I have analyzed the stack using gdb but it is not clear to me **how** the stack is aligned and **why** it is done that way. I hope that someone on SO can shed some light on the design of the call stack by gcc.

In textbooks, the common description of the stack, is implementation agnostic and typically leaves out a discussion of alignment, padding, and the hard boundaries of the call stack. I have an image to include but am too new to the site to be allowed to post images.

Comment: You seem to be confused about which way is **up** on the stack. But either way, EBP points to the middle. Function parameters are one direction, and local variables are the other direction relative to EBP. (That assumes of course that the function parameters are even on the stack, they could be passed in registers.) And yes, stack alignment is maintained by keeping the value in ESP aligned.

Comment: I understand that the stack grows toward lower addresses, and I am referring to the lowest address on the stack as the top of the stack. How is the offset for the arguments being passed to the called function accounted for? The size of the argument region could be different every time. Are these arguments part of the previous stack frame? Where is the padding inserted on the stack?

Comment: For functions with a fixed number of arguments, the offsets are computed at compile time. For functions with a variable number of arguments, the offsets are managed at runtime, see `man stdarg`. The arguments are at lower addresses than the local variables of the previous stack frame, and at higher addresses than the return address. So I'd say they're between the two stack frames. The compiler reserves space for local variables in the new stack frame by subtracting some multiple of the alignment from ESP. The local variables are located (with padding as needed) within that reserved space.

Comment: If the calling convention (for a 32-bit program) says that there is at least 16-byte alignment then the compiler (ie: GCC) will enforce it in code generation. The ABI has a stipulation that at the point just before doing a _CALL_ instruction the stack must be 16-byte aligned. This includes to the function `main`. Right after the CALL instruction executes the stack is misaligned by 4 bytes (CALL instruction puts the 4-byte return address on the stack).

Comment: If you know that at the first instruction of a function that the stack is 4 byte misaligned (and was 16-byte aligned before the CALL) you can compute alignment of variables on the stack. If you have no stack frame in your function (don't do the traditional PUSH EBP, MOV EBP, ESP) you can subtract 12 from ESP to be aligned once again. If you push EBP that subtracts 4 so to get realigned you would need to subtract an additional 8.

Comment: If you have local variables on the stack you can adjust the stack for those too. The compiler can compute the locations on the stack to properly align data. It is all based on the knowledge that you are guaranteed to be 4-byte misaligned when your function is executed and that before the CALL to your function it was aligned on a 16 byte boundary. This is all easy for a compiler to do, just more tedious for an assembly developer to do it by hand.